# arithemetic exception is thrown but why?

Tags: ios

Normally this exception is thrown on division by zero. The only prob is when I nslog the value of the variable in the denominator the value isn't zero. The code:

breuk.m

```
#import "breuk.h"

@implementation breuk
@synthesize tellerBreuk;
@synthesize noemerBreuk;
@synthesize ggd;
@synthesize quotientBreuk;

- (id)initWithTeller:(int)mijnTeller andNoemer:(int)mijnNoemer{

self = [super init];
if(self){
    int u = mijnTeller;
    int v = mijnNoemer;
    int temp;

    while (v != 0){
        temp = u % v;
        u = v;
        v = temp;
    }
    ggd = u;
    self.tellerBreuk = mijnTeller/ggd;
    self.noemerBreuk = mijnNoemer/ggd;
    NSLog(@"%i de ggd is %i", self.noemerBreuk, ggd);

    //self.quotientBreuk = (float)mijnTeller/mijnNoemer;
}
return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: How do you know it's not zero? You're logging after the divisions.

Comment: it gives a green error on self.tellerBreuk = mijnTeller /ggd; The nslog is performed though and says ggd not to be zero

Comment: if it throws exception on self.tellerBreuk = mijnTeller/ggd; line , your NSLog will not log anything , so add NSLog before that statement and check if ggd is not 0

Comment: that's the strange thing. I call this init with 2 different objects breuk and it performs that. So it doesn't stop and shows the correct nslog. But at the line self.tellerBreuk there's a green labeled error label Thread 1:exc_arithemetic(code= exc_1386_div, subcode=0x0)

Comment: found it, the third loop caused the warning

Answer (score 2):

See the comments:

```
if(self){
int u = mijnTeller; // For example u == 0
int v = mijnNoemer; // and v == 0
int temp;

while (v != 0){ // you don't come in while loop
    temp = u % v;
    u = v;
    v = temp;
}
ggd = u; // ggd is then == 0
self.tellerBreuk = mijnTeller/ggd; // Error: division by zero
self.noemerBreuk = mijnNoemer/ggd;
NSLog(@"%i de ggd is %i", self.noemerBreuk, ggd);
```

}

Comment: true but mijnTeller is 4 and mijnNoemer is 2. So ggd becomes 2 not 0